# Keep proportions of rectangle with css in any screen size

Tags: css

I have the next two elements in some rectangle view:

```
width:19%;
height: 20vh !important;
```

With the first element I save the width to be smaller every time I small the screen.

I can't use the same thing on the height, because the block I use it with is always changing its height, and just its width stays the same.

I thought something about:

```
width = "do 20% of what the height is"
```

And then I will be able to keep the exactly size of the rectangle in every size of the screen, (because the width will be always depends with the height - which depends on the width of the block they are in and which never changes.)

EDIT:
It's not the exact question like suggested below.
The "duplicate" talks about a container that always stay the same. My container is different because the height is changed every time!

Comment: Can you try something like this : `width : 4vh` and `height : 20vh`?

Comment: Tried this. i cant use it, because then its still big when i rezise just the width, and its not looking good with the rest of the page (which becoming small)